# ezSQL compiling issue on PHP V7

Tags: php

I've been developing my PHP Apps based on ezSQL class since 2000s. Unfortunately, I have depended on this class ever since. It was fine until I realized that this class isn't valid for servers running PHP 7+. When I run my App on servers running PHP 5.6 and below it works fine. Any other version above PHP 5.6 would give me this error:

```
Fatal Error: ezSQL_mysql requires mySQL Lib to be compiled and or linked in to the PHP engine
```

Unfortunately, the one who did this great class isn't working on it anymore since a long time. Is there any way around to fix this?

Comment: Does this link to a github thread help? https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/issues/2080

Comment: Does the guy in link means the config.php file on the server or my App?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the old ezSQL class, it uses libmysqlclient. PHP 7 no longer uses [libmysqlclient](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.php), leaving the old version of ezSQL useless. Upgrade to the new version of [ezSQL](https://github.com/ezSQL/ezsql) or access [this project](https://github.com/sunaryohadi/ezsql-mysqli) that updated the old class adapted for MySQLi.